# Regular expression to match same type of quotes

Tags: regex, bash, regex-lookarounds

Need Regular expression to match following strings.

```
["mystring"] -- Match
['mystring'] -- Match
["mystring'] -- No match
['mystring"] -- No match
```

I am trying with this `^\[(\"|\').*(\"|\')]$`, but this is matching the strings which do not have compatible quotes.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Programming language? What will work in JS/.NET won't work in Go / RE2. Try [`^\[([\"\']).*\1]$`](https://regex101.com/r/KuDM5x/2) if you are not sure. BTW, what about `['mystring"]  ["mystring']` - is that a valid scenario?

Comment: I am trying with bash, awk

Comment: Not valid, Quotes type should match

Comment: Could you please provide some code to reproduce the issue? Also, try `rx='^\[(['"'"'"])[^'"'"'"]*\1]$'; [[ $s =~ $rx ]] && echo "Matched!" || echo "No match!";` (if there can be no quotes at all inside the string). Or, if the strings cannot contain `]`, try `rx='^\[(['"'"'"])[^]]*\1]$';`/ Also, can the strings contain escaped `'` and `"`? What about `['my\'string']`? And can you expect `['my"string']`?

Comment: You say `["mystring'] ['mystring"]` is not valid, but it is actually a valid string. Do you mean the contents between quotes can only contain word chars? [`^\[(['"])[_[:alnum:]]*\1]$`](https://regex101.com/r/KuDM5x/5)

Comment: If you keep silent, we cannot help you. Please clarify your *requirements*. Guessing games are not quite helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Did any of my solutions work for you?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, it's working. 

Apologies for late reply, I had to take care of a medical emergency.

Comment: Which one? `^\[(['"])[_[:alnum:]]*\1]$`?

Comment: This is working for me.

`rx='^\[(['"'"'"])[^'"'"'"]*\1]$'; [[ $s =~ $rx ]] && echo "Matched!" || echo "No match!";`


Regex101 link also satisfying my need.

Comment: Just accepted your answer and upvoted it. Thank you very much  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need

```
rx='^\[(['"'"'"])[^'"'"'"]*\1]$';
[[ $s =~ $rx ]] && echo "Matched!" || echo "No match!";
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/grnMCl)

The pattern is `^\[(['"])[^'"]*\1]$` and it matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(['"])` - Capturing group 1: a `"` or `'`
- `[^'"]*` - zero or more `'` or `"` chars
- `\1` - the backreference to the value captured into Group 1
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.